# How to add tag for texture autodetect in Node Wrangler?

Tags: node-editor

[image]

[image]

[image]

I got some textures. I want to match it with *Node Wrangler* tags for auto texture detection.

I can find out

- `d`, `diffuse` = `Base Color`
- `b`= `Bump`
- `s` = `Specular`

Need advice to match these texture with *Node Wrangler*.

Comment: Hello and welcome, your question is not really clear, make sure to edit the question to describe it in a better way. The Node wrangler needs your textures to have the correct name for the different textures. For example: Fabric_diffuse.png, Fabric_bump.png, Fabric_specular.png, without the correct names, you need to manually add your textures to the correct area.

Comment: You need to go to the source of those images and see if they have a help section, FAQ, or contact information.  They're the only ones who will know for sure what they are using the suffixes n, o, and t for.

Comment: I'm guessing that the suffixes of these are b = base/diffuse, n = normal, n-disp = normal-displacement, o = occlusion, s = specular, t = transparent, d = displacement (d being for use w/o the normal map).

Comment: Yes, where should I fill  Occlusion, Transparent in Tags? Thank